# Parse login proceeding without valid credentails

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want my application to stop users from logging in without the proper credentials (much like every other application). I am using Parse and used their code under their iOS source documentation for the login sequence but as soon as I hit the login button without any credentials in, or even the wrong one, it still applies to the sucessfulLoginPage segue identifier without checking their credentials first. I have tried everything I know how to do without any success, can anybody help me out here? I have my code below.

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password:password) {
    (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if user != nil {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("sucessfulLoginPage", sender: self)
    } else if username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty {
        var emptyFieldsError:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Please try again", message: "Please fill in all the fields we can get you logged in to your account.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
        emptyFieldsError.show()
        self.loginActivity.hidden = true
        self.loginButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.loginButton.alpha = 1.0
        self.loginActivity.stopAnimating()

        self.usernameField.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.passwordField.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.forgotPasswordLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
    } else {
        self.loginActivity.hidden = true
        self.loginButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.loginButton.alpha = 1.0
        self.loginActivity.stopAnimating()

        self.usernameField.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.passwordField.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.forgotPasswordLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true

        var invalidLogin:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Please try again", message: "The username password combo you gave us does not match our records, please reset your password or try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
        invalidLogin.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because `user` is not `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen if you have enabled automatic user. Search of `PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()` in AppDelegate and remove or comment it out.

Comment: That was in the AppDelegate, but when I comment it out it still does it.

Comment: @TrentonTyler it still does it because there is probably still a cached user on device. Once a user is logged in they stay logged in until you tell the app to log them out. So just call `PFUser.logout` or whatever it is for swift just to make sure there is not logged in user for testing. or just delete the app and reinstall